# Spatial Downscaling of global temperature in R?

Tags: r, interpolation, spatial-statistics, gstat, downscaling

I am interested in spatial downscaling of global temperature to grid cell.

What I have is a vector of future annual global temperature values which I would like to downscale to (hopefully) 0.5°.

Is this possible in R?

```
year  Temperature
2016  0.8630774
2017  0.8924077
2018  0.9221504
2019  0.9522887
2020  0.982807
2021  1.013691
```

I have read about the `gstat`, `spataEco`, and `gdalUtils` packages for statistical downscaling using regressions.

Could someone guide/provide me with an example of downscaling the global data to a finer scale using covariates such as altitude, slope, aspect etc?